# How can I change Python version in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python3, sublime-text

I am using Sublime Text 3 in Ubuntu. The default Python is `python2` which Sublime uses when I build program using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

I am trying to run code as,

```
print(f"Player {row[0]} Vertically =")
```

but it gives error as follows because code is run with default Python

```
File "/home/gd/Desktop/python/python-revision/pp_13_iterators_iterables.py", line 41
  print(f"Player {row[0]} Vertically =")
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/gd/Desktop/python/python-revision/pp_13_iterators_iterables.py"]
[dir: /home/gd/Desktop/python/python-revision]
```

However, when I run same program from terminal, using `python3` it works as expected.

```
$ python3 pp_13_iterators_iterables.py
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
Vertically
Player 1 Vertically =
```

How can I change default build environment of Sublime Text to Python 3 and build it using shortcut as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>?

I tried using alias as

```
alias python="/usr/bin/python3.6"
```

but it didn't work and gave same error as previous.

Comment: I found this on sublime forum but couldn't apply. https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/select-which-version-of-python-to-run-build/1695/8

Comment: In order to apply what you found on the sublime forum, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789410/how-to-edit-sublime-text-build-settings).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing alias just changes the default python version when `python` as a command is called. But Sublime uses path `/usr/bin/python` when building python source. I strongly suggest you to roll back the alias definition.

Now to build your code using `python3`, you can either install `python-is-python3` package which is available on 20.04 and higher to invoke `python3` using `python` **or** create a new build system and set that build system as default.

The package `python-is-python3` **should be avoided** if there are some existing packages which depend on Python 2. If you don't have such packages, install the above said package using

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

**Alternatively**, to add a new build system,

- Go to *Tools→Build System→New Build System*

  [image: Screenshot]
- A new tab will be opened to create a new build system. Paste this

  ```
  {
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
  }
  ```
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save it. Rename it to Python3.
- Now to make Python3 as default, go to *Tools→Build System* and select newly created build system, here Python3.
- (optional) Create a new `.py` file to check whether it has been changed and paste this

  ```
  import sys
  print("Sublime is using: ", sys.version)
  ```
- Build your source using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- If the output is like

  ```
  Sublime is using:  3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
  [GCC 8.2.0]
  [Finished in 0.1s]
  ```

That means that code is built using `python3`.

Comment: It's working now as https://imgur.com/a/Zp7mfDF.

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh I just noticed that I mistyped python version in rolling back the alias. So have a look at there again and change your alias back to python2 using `alias python="/usr/bin/python"`

Comment: Hi @Kulfy, I tried the same approach that you have given above but my default version is still python2 not python3 on Sublime. I am on ubuntu-mate OS. Can you please let me know where am I making the mistake?

Comment: @AlphaBet What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python`?

Comment: @Kulfy, here is the output `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 16 2018 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7`

Comment: @AlphaBet And what about `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`? Have you saved the new build system and chosen that while building python source code?

Comment: @Kulfy here is the output `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
`  -- Yes, I saved the new build system and chosen that while building python source code

Comment: @AlphaBet Please ask a new question with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

if you use python comes with anaconda, you probably need to use the following (it is the case for me at least)

```
{
  "cmd": ["path to anaconda/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
}
```